# Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am running test on Java using selenium.

When I ran sample test. I am getting the following

```
Build info: version: '2.47.2', revision: '4d972c01cab1304452627f837654326a11eb92fe', time: '2015-09-24 09:17:17'
System info: host: 'lima', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:133)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1443602965766   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1443602966724   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1443602966725   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"W4MC2I4gSaDP","location":"app-profile","version":"2.47.1","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/tmp/anonymous2411601304142570791webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1443602959000,"updateDate":1443602959000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":8234871,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"66.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1443602966725   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
1443602966736   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1443602966739   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1443602966739   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"W4MC2I4gSaDP","location":"app-profile","version":"2.47.1","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"/tmp/anonymous2411601304142570791webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1443602959000,"updateDate":1443602959000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":8234871,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"66.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1443602966740   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1443602970172   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1443602970172   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1443602970172   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1443602971358   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1443602971358   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1443602971359   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1443602971422   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1443602971426   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1443602971427   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1443602971433   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1443602971450   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1443602971450   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1443602971450   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1443602971477   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1443602971487   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1443602971502   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 44 more


Results :

Failed tests:   test(test.SampleTest): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: (..)
```

My dependency version is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Firefox Version is 41.0b8

I hope this will be resolved when firefox and selenium version are matched.

Can anyone tell me which selenium version match with firefox- 41.0b8 version

Answer (score 0):

I don't think latest version of selenium supports firefox 41.0 beta version. Moreover you are referring to a beta version instead of a stable version. Downgrade your browser to version that the latest version of selenium supports. To check for the change logs of selenium

- [Selenium Change Log in Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG).

As of this post, `Selenium v2.47` supports `firefox v39`. Hope it helps.